# Define a function as a member without executing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs3

I have a `Ext` obj with 2 pdf files. When these files get rendered, I want to check to see if a user is logged in before they download the file. I thought I could achieve this through `onclick` attribute but the code runs after the page is loaded and the message appears immediately.

```
function download(url) {
    if (hasRights(url)) {
        //window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=480,width=640,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes', false);
        return true;
    } else {
        if (checkLoggedIn()) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Insufficient Rights');
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var treeObj = [];
treeObj.push({text: 'Ex 1', leaf:true, href:download('/ex.pdf'), cls:'tree-pdf'});
treeObj.push({text: 'Ex 2', leaf:true, href:download('/ex2.pdf'), cls:'tree-pdf'});
```

How do I get an onclick function within an `extjs`

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really specific to extjs.

The way you define the object with the function as member is not correct. If you want to define a function as a member of an object, you must not call it directly like you do. You have two options :

1. Save the function first to a variable, and pass it the url with `bind` :

   ```
   var downloadFn = function (url) {
      if (hasRights(url)) {
      (...) 
   };
   treeObj.push({text: 'Ex 1', leaf:true, href:downloadFn.bind(null, '/ex.pdf'), cls:'tree-pdf'});
   ```
2. Create a new function that calls the original :

   ```
   function download(url) {
       (...) 
   }
   treeObj.push({text: 'Ex 1', leaf:true, href:function () {
       download('/ex.pdf')
   } , cls:'tree-pdf'});
   ```

Comment: Both of these options fail to recognize the function. They instead try to direct the click to `downloadFn.bind(null, '/ex.pdf')` which throws a 404